# Reading <no data> with POI event user model

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am not sure if I have understood properly, but I think if I use the POI Event model, and there is no data (just blank, not even a space) in a excel column, the data is not read at all.
The problem I have is say I have a model with 15 columns and I am reading the data to populate the model from a excel sheet.
I read the excel and store the data in a List and then add to the model
If one of the column has no data, POI reads nothing and hence the List I create has only 14 columns.
And then I cannot match the columns in the model and the List.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Is this for .xls (HSSF) or .xlsx (XSSF)? (The way to solve it differs, as the code for both is low level being event user model)

Comment: It is for xlsx, I am using XSSF and SAX (Event API) for reading the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using HSSF for a .xls file, you could have used [MissingRecordAwareHSSFListener](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/MissingRecordAwareHSSFListener.html) which would have sent you special records to indicate gaps. A good example for that is [XLS2CSVmra](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/hssf/eventusermodel/examples/XLS2CSVmra.java). However, you say you're on XSSF for .xlsx, so it's a little different

The is an Apache POI example that covers missing records in a .xlsx file, you'll want to look at the [XLSX2CSV example](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/xssf/eventusermodel/XLSX2CSV.java). Basically, you should have a variable that holds the last column number you saw. When the `startElement` fires for `c` (cell), check the reference column against the last one seen. If there's a gap, trigger empty cells to your logic at that point, then record the new column and process.

The logic to get the current column number would be something like:

```
// Get the cell reference
String r = attributes.getValue("r");
int firstDigit = -1;
for (int c = 0; c < r.length(); ++c) {
    if (Character.isDigit(r.charAt(c))) {
         firstDigit = c;
         break;
    }
}
thisColumn = nameToColumn(r.substring(0, firstDigit));
```

Don't forget to reset the column counter on a new row (`endElement` for `row` is often a good one to trigger that on)

Comment: Thanks you for all the suggestions, I will try out these solutions and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gagravarr, for giving me the initial idea to solve the problem.
I did not follow, exactly what you suggested though. Instead what I did is, I compared the characters (ASCII values) from the column references, the current one and the last one.
I kept track of the last column reference and checked that the difference between two column reference should always be 1 i.e. B1 - A1 == 1. 
Any deviation from this I considered as a skipping of a column. 
The solution works perfectly, below is a snippet of what I did:

```
   char currColChar = attributes.getValue("r").charAt(0);
   // Check if we have missed a column due to no data
   if ((currColChar - lastColumnChar) > 1) {
                //logic for column skipped
   }
   lastColumnChar = currColChar;
```